# is Android module dependency increase apk size

Tags: android

I have an android app separated into several modules.

It is traveling app but it will be for different clients.

with every client may I need to change only hotel or car screen, colors or images.

so I make every part of the app as library modules.

for example:

App Module

Config Module >> like base URLs, colors, facebook or twitter secret keys, etc

Utility Module >> like notification helpers, volley helpers

Hotel Module, Car Module, etc

in utility module, I need a drawable from config module and many modules depend on config module

if I make several modules depend on Config module when I generate apk is the apk size will have redundant Config module or there is another way to achieve my goal?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use build variants with gradle.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

So your global architecture is in normal folder and differents files are in the matching folder.

eg:

```
app
| - src
    | - main
    |   | - java 
    |        | - com.xxxx.yy
    |            | your code
    |
    | — car
    |   | - java 
    |   |    | - com.xxxx.yy
    |   |        | specificClass.java
    |   | - res
    |       | - drawable
    |           | - main.png
    |
    | - hotel
        | - java 
        |    | - com.xxxx.yy
        |        | specificClass.java
        | - res
            | - drawable
                | - main.png
```

then you could call your main.png img in your code. When building, choose to compile with `car` or `hotel` flavor and then your app would have the correct image.

It work the same with `string.xml` for example, or with java classes.

Just factorize your global code in the main folder, then put your specific code in matching folder.

Comment: I have handled "branding" of apps using gradle, I would definitely recommend this method. To make this answer complete I would provide a simple example.

Comment: I checked the docs but I found that it is for different apk variants in docs "Gradle creates a total of 12 build"

Comment: @zgc7009 it's not branding only but maybe I need to change flight layout or car screen logic

Comment: You would be amazed at what gradle can manage on a per build basis. Some things may seem hacky, but you can gain a lot of granular control from gradle.

Comment: @amorenew it's not only for branding, you could change java classes too. I edit my response.

Comment: @milcaepsilon thanks, I will try your solution and I will give you feedback

Comment: but anyway If I use my current way is using config module as a dependency for several modules will increase apk size?

Comment: @amorenew anything that gets built into the apk, regardless of how it is built into it, will increase apk size.

Comment: @milcaepsilon I read the docs but I think "flavor build" is not what I need so I am trying another solution I will post it later.

Comment: @milcaepsilon for more flexible solution I should use cross platform framework too

Comment: Dependency that we add for androidTest will increase the size of apk?